# Java Switch Incompatible Types Boolean Int

Tags: java, boolean, switch-statement, compiler-errors

I have the following class:

```
public class NewGameContract {

  public boolean HomeNewGame = false;
  public boolean AwayNewGame = false;

  public boolean GameContract() {
    if (HomeNewGame && AwayNewGame){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use it like so:

```
if (networkConnection) {
  connect4GameModel.newGameContract.HomeNewGame = true;
  boolean status = connect4GameModel.newGameContract.GameContract();

  switch (status) {
    case true: break;
    case false: break;
  }
  
  return;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
incompatible types found: boolean required: int on the following
`switch (status)` code.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a side note, your `GameContract` method could simply be `return HomeNewGame && AwayNewGame`.

Comment: thanks for all the info. im trying to learn C# and Java, and this is something they process differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't switch on a `boolean` (which only have 2 values anyway):

The Java Language Specification clearly specifies what type of expression can be `switch`-ed on.

#### [JLS 14.11 The switch statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.11)

> ```
> SwitchStatement:
>     switch ( Expression ) SwitchBlock
> ```
>
> The type of the `Expression` must be `char`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `Character`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, or an `enum` type, or a compile-time error occurs.

It is a lot more readable and concise to simply use an `if` statement to distinguish the two cases of `boolean`.

Answer (score 9):

you don't want to `switch` on a boolean, just use a simple `if`/`else`

```
if (status) {
  ....
} else {
  ....
}
```

edit : `switch` is only used for `int`s, `char`s, or `enum`s (i think that's all, maybe there are others?)
edit edit : it seems `short` and `byte` are also valid types for switching, as well as the boxed versions of all of these (`Integer`, `Short`, etc etc)

Comment: byte and short, and anything with a narrowing cast (long, float double)

Comment: oh, and it seems that java7 might even (FINALLY) include support for switching on String too! yay! http://tech.puredanger.com/java7/#switch

Answer (score 2):

Switch statements in Java can use byte, short, char, and int (note: not long) primitive data types or their corresponding wrapper types. Starting with J2SE 5.0, it became possible to use enum types. Starting with Java SE 7, it became possible to use Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Can't use boolean in switch, only int.  Please read the Java docs for the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, switch only works for byte, short, char, int and enum. For booleans you should use if/else as there are a very limited number of states.

Answer (score 1):

Switch takes an integer value, and a boolean cannot be converted to an integer.

In java, a boolean is a type in its own right, and not implicitly convertible to any other type (except Boolean).